# How to include UserControl and Model in MVC2 view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have UserControl as well as Model for particular view.  Usercontrol is working properly at the same time i try to include radiobutton on the same view with model. I am getting the Error:"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.DataTable', but this dictionary requires a model item of type "MyModelName"".

So can you please help anyone.

thanks,
Mohan

Comment: Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<RegistrationModel>" and I have included the Usercontrol "<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/SecondaryMenu.ascx"); %>", Now i try to binf the readiobutton "<%= Html.RadioButton("radio_button", Model.rdbCutomerType)%> Yes 
<%= Html.RadioButton("radio_button", !Model.rdbCutomerType)%> No"

Comment: In the controller while returning the view, what are you passing ? You have to write something like this "return View(modelInstance)". Where model instance is of type RegistrationModel.

Comment: I understand but i need both, now i am passing something like this return View(CMenuBulider.LoadMenu()) // this is for usercontrol. So now i need usercontrol as well as Model. How can i?

Comment: I believe user control can use the model of the View. What version of .net framework are you using ?

Comment: I am not using model for user control. I using .Net 3.5 and MVC2

Answer (score 0):

The Exception Message is very descriptive and says it all. your view accepts a different model and you are passing different model to this view in controller.
Look at two places

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 

Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<AcceptedModel>" %>
```

and in your controller you would have something like

```
public ActionResult action()
{
    SentModel model = new SentModel(); 
    return View(SentModel); //i believe typeof(SentModel) != typeof(AcceptedModel) that is what is causing problem
}
```

**Edit** you can use viewModel that can contain all values required by the view

```
public class MYViewModel
{
    System.Data.DataTable MyTable{get;set;}
    Registration Myregistration{get;set;}
}
```

now in controller you can populate your viewModel like

```
public ActionResult MyActionResult(int id)
{
   MyViewModel mdl = new MyViewModel();
   mdl.Myregistration = new Registration();
   mdl.MyTable = //code to populate table
   return View(mdl);
}
```

and in the view you should update it to accept MyViewModel type

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 

Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyViewModel>" %>
```

and then you can access them in view using

```
<%foreach( var row in Model.MyTable){}%>
and <%:Model.MyRegistration.FirstName%>
```

Comment: I understand but i need both, now i am passing something like this return View(CMenuBulider.LoadMenu()) // this is for usercontrol. So now i need usercontrol as well as Model. How can i?

Comment: @Mohanraj if u can paste your controller and view code, we might help. i have no idea what u are calling user control that you intend to pass from controller

Comment: <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.Data.DataTable>" %>

<% 
    int i = 0;
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows)
    { 
       %>
<a href="<%= Url.Content(ResourceLocation)%>%>">
                                <%=row["DisplayText"].ToString()%>
                            </a> } %>


My Model is:

public class Registration
    {
        public bool rdbCutomerType { get; set; }
    }
Controller:
public ActionResult CustomerView(int id)
        {
            Registration reg = new Registration();
            return View(reg);
        }

Comment: @Mohanraj i updated my answer plz read it again and if u need more than one models on view always put them in one ViewModel